# Search for hardcoded accounts in files

Tags: powershell

I've been trying to build a PowerShell script to scan for files containing hardcoded accounts based on regex pattern. The simple script works fine, but as additional I'm looping through Disks and it keeps failing to output any results.

As the script try to scan drive once and recursively loop through each file, the foreach loop adds second drive in the end, i.e. "C:\Windows\D". Feel like I'm close but struggling to wrap around my head around how to adjust the script. Please see shared script and if you'd have any suggestions on how to fix this part of any reference to documents are very much appreciated.

```
#Target one asset for testing
$targetSystems = @(
    @{
        Domain = "domain"
        OU = "OU=,DC=,DC="
        Asset = ""
    }
)

$drives = @(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem | Where-Object { $_.Free -gt 0 } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

$fileTypes = @("*.txt", "*.ini", "*.conf", "*.config", "*.xml", "*.ps1", "*.bat", "*.vbs", "*.c", "*.cpp", "*.cs", "*.java", "*.mdb", "*.accdb", "*.db", "*.sql", "*.html", "*.php", "*.aspx", "*.log")

$regexPatterns = @(
    "(?i)(pwd|password|pass|secret)\s*=\s*(.+)",
    "mysql:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "postgresql:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "sqlserver:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "oracle:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "(?:api_key|apikey|api-key)\s*=\s*(\w+)",
    "(?:access_token|access-token|token)\s*=\s*(\w+)",
    "smtp:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "pop3:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "imap:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "ssh:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "rdp:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "aws:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "azure:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "gcp:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@",
    "domain=([^;]+);user=([^;]+);password=([^;]+)"
)

$results = @()

#Drive scan with file types and regex pattern search

foreach ($drive in $drives) {
  $pathToScan = Join-Path -Path $drive -ChildPath $fileType
  $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $pathToScan -Recurse -filter $fileType
    if ($files) {
        foreach ($fileType in $fileTypes) {
            $filteredFiles = $files | Where-Object { $_.Name -like $fileType }
            foreach ($file in $filteredFiles) {
                try {
                    $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw
                    foreach ($regexPattern in $regexPatterns) {
                        $matches = [regex]::Matches($content, $regexPattern)
                        foreach ($match in $matches) {
                            $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
                                Domain = $domain
                                Asset = $asset
                                Drive = $drive
                                Path = $file.FullName
                                Match = $match.Groups[1].Value
                                Value = $match.Groups[2].Value
                            }
                            $results += $result
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch {
                    Write-Host "Error scanning file: $($file.FullName) - $_"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# Saving results to CSV file
$results | Export-Csv -Path "Path\To\Results.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

# Output results to console
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

Write-Host "Script execution completed. Results have been saved to Results.csv."
```

Comment: Try adding exception handler to code to find out reason for failures.  Most likely you do no have permission to read a file(s).